# Why aren't fully compile-checked languages being designed?

Tags: programming-languages

Forgive the terribly designed pseudocode, but I hope it gets the point across:

```
float sqrt takes float n : [0,inf)
    // fancy algorithm
    return result

void main
    x = sqrt -1             // Compilation error
    y = sqrt float.max      // This works
    z = (y + 1) * (y + 1)   // Compilation error (this would result in overflow)
```

During compilation, the compiler analyzes the `sqrt` function and characterizes it as

```
sqrt : [0,float.max] -> [0, sqrt float.max[
```

It does this by doing the same thing with the `+, -, *, /` operators.

---

In the `main` function, the first statement does not compile because `sqrt` does not accept negative input. The third statement does not compile because the `*` operator takes only input that would result in an output of `[float.min, float.max]`.

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for are languages like COQ, Agda and Idris, where the type system allows types to be parametrized by values. (dependent types)

This is not as easy as you might think and requires usually a full proof (at the call side) that the condition is met. In your case, you'd have to proove that the argument for sqrt cannot be negative. This is simple in the case of

```
sqrt(5)
```

but not so easy in the following case:

```
sqrt(some_long_computation_on_floats(f))
```

You'd need to proove here that `some_long_computation_on_floats` will return only positive numbers. Which may or may not be possible.

Comment: The point of designing the language is so we can discover what range of numbers `some_long_computation_on_floats(f)` falls into. Essentially, `+,-,*,/` and all standard library functions would all have contracts. If you made a function without a contract, when you called it you'd have to handle the case where the number you got back from the condition isn't suitable for where you're pumping it next. Essentially, the programming language holds your hand and makes it neigh impossible to leave out an edge case or call a function with invalid input.

Comment: @CalebJares I really suggest trying one of the above mentioned languages. They are great, but you'll be surprised how many seemingly trivial things you must proove. In the field of inexact (floating point) arithmetic, where not even `(a-b) = (a+42)-(b+42)` holds, I guess you'll get lost.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot. For floating point operations I was imagining the IDE would suggest a delta value (assuming the compiler could calculate the highest delta value from the operations). Ex: for `(a+42)-(b+42)`, there are two `+` operations and one `-` operations. If `+` has an imprecision (delta) value of `a` and `-` is `b`, then `d=2a+b` (assuming `a` and `b` are defined to be positive). Coming back to the IDE, I would hope it would autocomplete or like Resharper, press `ctrl`+`space` to insert the delta.

Comment: @CalebJares The IDE would have to know the actual value for this. How can it know those values, if, for example, a and b are arguments to a function?

Comment: That's the cool thing, if a and b are arguments, then they come from somewhere. It can eventually walk all the way up to where they were set and see what range of values they could have (because every function has strict definitions)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to read up on [design by contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). In particular, there are many languages and language extensions that support setting complex contracts in your code, and some of those may be checked at compile-time. A straightforward example is [JML](http://www.eecs.ucf.edu/~leavens/JML/index.shtml) - in fact, the first page of [this paper about JML](http://www.eecs.ucf.edu/~leavens/JML//jmldbc.pdf) has the following `sqrt` contract:

```
//@ requires x >= 0.0;
//@ ensures JMLDouble.approximatelyEqualTo(x, \result * \result, eps);
public static double sqrt(double x) {
    /*...*/
}
```

And there are indeed tools that can check for contract violations without running the code, such as [ESC/Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESC/Java).

Now, design by contract is actually very popular because type declarations in statically-typed languages *are* in fact a form of contract. More complex contracts, however, are far less popular, I'd say because:

1. Writing complex contracts can get *really* verbose *really* fast.
2. Bugs can creep into complex contracts, and this brings you back to square 1 - who will check the contracts?
3. Checking complex contracts at compile-time is usually:

   1. Computationally expensive
   2. Generates a lot of false positives (or worse, has false negatives)
4. There are other accepted techniques of checking the code, most commonly using automated tests.